# Methods of getting an address of array element with gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Let's say we have an array

```
char arr[10]
```

Why are these not the same? gdb outputs different address.

```
display/w &arr[10] - /x &arr+10 = 0x7ffc85c8b9f4
display/w &arr+10 -  /x &arr[10] = 0x7ffc85c770f9
```

I understand these as

1. The address of the tenth element of arr.
2. The address of the tenth byte of arr, where a char is 1 byte.

Comment: `&arr[10]` is `&(arr[10])`, which is the address of the tenth element of the array `arr`. `&arr` is a pointer to the entire array, not a pointer to an element (same starting place in memory but different type). So `&arr + 10` would be a pointer to ten arrays beyond `arr`, not to the tenth element of `arr`. `&(arr + 10)` would be a pointer to the tenth element of `arr`.

Comment: To show the address, do `display &arr[10]` (without the `/w`). Giving `display` a size letter option turns it into an `x`  command, which will treat the argument as an address and display the contents of memory at that address.